# How do I move the TeamCity cache directory root?

Tags: teamcity

My installation of TeamCity 3.1 (yeah, it is old!) (installed on a Windows XP box) holds its temporary files under `C:/TCBWork`.  How can I move that root?   I would like to move it to another disk for better space management.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about build agent working directory, it is set in buildAgent/conf/buildAgent.properties file (local TeamCity agent is under TeamCity/buildAgent directory).

And given that you have non-standard location for it, you'd already changed it previously :)

Answer (score 2):

This might be a stupid answer, but assuming you're using NTFS you could mount an entirely different drive to the folder location of TCBWork.